# select case to find out frequency for each product in MySQL

Tags: mysql

this is my fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b1cd7079b2ec78c0e9a9df1b1ccccb4b

i have 2 tables

```
 CREATE TABLE slider_products(
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    product_id INT(10) UNSIGNED,
    slider_id INT UNSIGNED);
    
    
    CREATE TABLE slider_master(
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    product_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);
    
    
    
    INSERT INTO slider_products (product_id, slider_id)
    VALUES(147,1),
    (147,2),
    (146,2),
    (148,3);
    
    INSERT INTO slider_master(product_id)
    VALUES(147),
    (148),
    (146),
    (146);
    
    
    table slider_product 
    
    +----+------------+-----------+
    | id | product_id | slider_id |
    +----+------------+-----------+
    |  1 |        147 |         1 |
    |  2 |        147 |         2 |
    |  3 |        146 |         2 |
    |  4 |        148 |         3 |
    +----+------------+-----------+
    
    
    table slider_master
    
    +----+------------+
    | id | product_id |
    +----+------------+
    |  1 |        147 |
    |  2 |        148 |
    |  3 |        146 |
    |  4 |        146 |
    +----+------------+

SELECT product_id, COUNT(product_id) FROM slider_products GROUP BY product_id

+------------+-------------------+
| product_id | COUNT(product_id) |
+------------+-------------------+
|        146 |                 1 |
|        147 |                 2 |
|        148 |                 1 |
+------------+-------------------+


SELECT product_id, COUNT(product_id) FROM slider_master GROUP BY product_id;

+------------+-------------------+
| product_id | COUNT(product_id) |
+------------+-------------------+
|        146 |                 2 |
|        147 |                 1 |
|        148 |                 1 |
+------------+-------------------+
```

i want to compare for each product_id for the frequencies, if the frequencies not same, then put 'no-identical' otherwise, put 'identical' on it.

i've tried with this query

```
SELECT CASE WHEN count1.product_id = count2.product_id THEN 'identical' ELSE 'not-identical' END AS statement, count1.product_id FROM (SELECT product_id, COUNT(product_id) FROM slider_products GROUP BY product_id) AS count1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT product_id, COUNT(product_id) FROM slider_master GROUP BY product_id) AS count2
ON count1.product_id = count2.product_id;
```

but why it produce this:

```
+-----------+------------+
| statement | product_id |
+-----------+------------+
| identical |        146 |
| identical |        147 |
| identical |        148 |
+-----------+------------+
```

instead, if we look at both tables, the result should be like this

```
+---------------+------------+
|   statement   | product_id |
+---------------+------------+
| not-identical |        146 |
| not-identical |        147 |
| identical     |        148 |
+---------------+------------+
```

Comment: Frequencies? what are they?

Comment: sorry, it means count the product_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your current approach is that you are comparing the `product_id` values, not the counts.  Of course, the two `product_id` values will always be the same.  Assuming that `slider_master` has all `product_id` values, then your current approach is valid, and we can just aggregate the two tables in separate subqueries and then join them:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN sm.cnt = sp.cnt THEN 'identical' ELSE 'not-identical' END AS statement,
    sm.product_id
FROM
(
    SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM slider_master
    GROUP BY product_id
) sm
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM slider_product
    GROUP BY product_id
) sp
    ON sp.product_id = sm.product_id
ORDER BY
    sm.product_id;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: thankyou very much, what i want to know is, which part that i not do to produce just like yours?

Comment: @18818181881 You are comparing `product_id` values instead of the counts.

Comment: if i put slider_product first, can i make it ```join``` instead ```left join```?

Comment: The reason for the left (over inner) join is that perhaps `slider_product` does not have every `product_id` which appears in the `slider_master` table.  If that were the case, doing an inner join would filter off products.  Assuming all products exist in both tables, then yes, you may do an inner join.